# how to search user bookmark only?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write sql query to show search throw resource that user's bookmarked. my problem is when user type keyword the search will search all resource on the website and including his bookmark I want to be able to search user bookmark

```
SELECT
    a.Id ,
    a.summary ,
    a.pageId ,
    a.name ,
    a.createdOn ,
    a.userID ,
    Total
FROM Resources AS a
LEFT JOIN Topics_Resources AS b ON a.Id = b.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN Skills_Resources AS c ON a.Id = c.ResourceID
INNER JOIN Modules AS m ON a.ModuleId = m.ModuleID
INNER JOIN ContentItems AS ci ON m.ModuleID = ci.ModuleID
INNER JOIN Tabs AS t ON t.TabID = ci.TabID
INNER JOIN TabModules AS tb ON t.TabID = tb.TabID
INNER JOIN Bookmarks ON a.Id = Bookmarks.resourceID
INNER JOIN Bookmarks AS Bookmarks_1 ON a.Id = Bookmarks_1.resourceID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        r.Id , COUNT(l.resourceId) Total
    FROM resources r
    LEFT JOIN likes l ON r.Id = l.resourceid
    GROUP BY r.Id
)
l ON a.Id = l.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN HtmlText AS h ON tb.ModuleID = h.ModuleID
WHERE (h.content LIKE '%winter%')
OR (t.description LIKE '%winter%')
OR (t.keywords LIKE '%winter%')
OR (a.summary LIKE '%winter%')
AND Bookmarks.userID = '695A8626-A28B-4308-AD9B-D5AC576B4E5A'
GROUP BY    a.Id ,
            a.summary ,
            a.pageId ,
            a.name ,
            a.createdOn ,
            a.userID ,
            Total
ORDER BY a.createdOn DESC
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? are do you want the user to search his bookmark or ALL bookmarks except his or something else?

Comment: So you wrote this entire query and don't know the function of parentheses (), OR and AND? Your AND is only combining the userID condition to your last OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try enclosing every OR in brackets

```
SELECT  a.Id, a.summary, a.pageId, a.name, a.createdOn,a.userID,Total
FROM         Resources AS a 
LEFT JOIN Topics_Resources AS b ON a.Id = b.ResourceID 
LEFT JOIN Skills_Resources AS c ON a.Id = c.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN Modules AS m ON a.ModuleId = m.ModuleID 
INNER JOIN ContentItems AS ci ON m.ModuleID = ci.ModuleID 
INNER JOIN Tabs AS t ON t.TabID = ci.TabID 
INNER JOIN TabModules AS tb ON t.TabID = tb.TabID 
INNER JOIN Bookmarks ON a.Id = Bookmarks.resourceID 
INNER JOIN Bookmarks AS Bookmarks_1 ON a.Id = Bookmarks_1.resourceID 
INNER JOIN (select r.Id, count(l.resourceId) Total
            from resources r
            left join likes l on r.Id = l.resourceid
            group by r.Id)  l 
    on a.Id  = l.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HtmlText AS h ON tb.ModuleID = h.ModuleID 
where ((h.content like '%winter%') or ( t.description like '%winter%') or ( t.keywords like '%winter%') or ( a.summary like '%winter%'))
    and Bookmarks.userID='695A8626-A28B-4308-AD9B-D5AC576B4E5A'
GROUP BY  a.Id, a.summary, a.pageId, a.name, a.createdOn,a.userID,Total  
ORDER BY a.createdOn DESC
```

Note: if you expect big quantity of data, this kind of query will last hours. you should add FULLTEXT